# Android mp3 service

Tags: java, android, android-service, audio-player, android-music-player

So, I have mp3 player. I want, that all playback will be unkilled, so it will not stops. 
I tried services, and I have several problems:

**1. Service communication with activity:**
I can start service with data passing in intent
I can send via broadcast resiever data **from *service* to activity**
How I can send data **from activity to *service***?
Do I really need to do like

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Flags flag = Flags.values()[intent.getIntExtra("flag", 0)];
    switch(flag) {
        case Start:
            //Starts the playback
            break;
        case Repeat:
            //Do stuff
            stopSelf() //How to stop it right: stop this, but leave first call?
            break;
        case Shuffle:
            //Do stuff
            stopSelf()
            break;
        case Move:
            //Do stuff
            stopSelf()
            break;
        case Song:
            //Do stuff
            stopSelf()
            break;
        case GetData:
            //Do stuff
            stopSelf()
            break;
        default:
            //Do stuff
            stopSelf()
            break;
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

And each message makes me start new service, with all the consequences

**2. Immortal service:**
For Immortal service do I need to use intent service. Or not? I didn't find too much docs about it.

**4. Notifications:**
Also, I want to do something like [notification with control-buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlJaj.png)

**5. Docs:**
I didn't find too much docs at all for services. And what I found was 2-3 years old =(
I will be grateful for any help ^_^
At least, say, what I need to use: service or intentservice?

Comment: I'm think that i need binding service :/

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too many questions in this thread. I'll try my best to answer as much as possible as I can not seem to understand what you are saying.

*1. Service communication with activity:* 
If you want to communicate between an activity and a service use a `BroadcastReceiver`

*2. Background:*
I don't know what you really mean here, I'm guessing you want something that will not be killed when your app goes to the background. For that use a `Service`. A service is designed for executing code when your app in not in the foreground. It runs on the main thread just like an activity and it may be killed when the system runs low on memory

*3. Do I need a service at all?*
Yes!! unless you want your song(s) to stop playing when your app goes to the background

*4. Notifications:* Read the android [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

Comment: 1. How to send data from activity to running service? 2. I mean unkilled service. But simple service is killed (when i long tap home button and kill my app, service stops too), so how to create unkilled service?

Comment: Use a BroadcastReceiver as I said to. [This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) tutorial will show you how

Comment: Thanks, i tried BR to do it, but it didn't work. I'll try this stuff

Comment: Do i need to use intentservice?